# Using $stateParams to get float from URL, returning null value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to take two float variables in the URL using $stateParams (latitude and longitude) and assign them to Google Map's 'center' object. Both latitude and longitude end up being null values, and I think it has to do with this line:

```
var center = { latitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lat), longitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lon) };
```

Here is the page so you can see the alert, which displays JSON.stringify(center): http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl4/#/49.2/-122.6

And here is my JS file:

```
(function (window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.router'])



  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('location', {
          url: '/:lat/:lon',
          templateUrl: 'index.html',
          controller: 'MapsCtrl',
          params: { //set default values (not sure if it does anything)
              lat: '80', 
              lon: '-122'
          },
          resolve: {
              resolveMap: function (MapService, $stateParams) {
                  return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon);
              }
          }
      });

  })

  .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (GoogleMapApi) {
      GoogleMapApi.configure({
          key: 'AIzaSyCbRPhVlxgVwBC0bBOgyB-Dn_K8ONrxb_g',
          v: '3',
          libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
      });
  } ])


    .controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams",
      function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams) {
          $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;

//Is this center variable using $stateParams correctly?
          var center = { latitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lat), longitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lon) };
          alert(JSON.stringify(center));
          //Object.freeze(center); caused TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ('latitude') ...

          $scope.map = {
              center: center,
              pan: false,
              zoom: 16,
              refresh: false,
              events: {},
              bounds: {}
          };

          $scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },

              fill: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  opacity: 0.5
              },
              geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
              draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
              editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
              events: {
                  dblclick: function () {
                      $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                  },
                  radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                      var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                      $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                  }
              }
          }





          //Increase Radius:
          $interval(function () {
              $scope.map.circle.radius += 30; //dynamic var
              $state.transitionTo('location', { //location is the state name
                  center: $stateParams.center,
                  radius: $scope.map.circle.radius
              },
    {
        notify: false
    });
          }, 1000); //end of interval function


      } ]); //end of controller

})(window, angular);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example/assets/stylesheets/example.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="website_libs/dev_deps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/0.0.1/dist/index.js"></script><script src="dist/angular-google-maps_dev_mapped.js"></script>
    <script src="getLoc.js"></script>
    <script src="searchRadius.js"></script>

    <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_g7xCYEi-U54SYfTXQ_lukRsChkWgjXQ'></script>

    <title>Pet Locate</title>

    <!--NEW STUFF FROM TOM-->


</head>

<body style="height: 100%">



<div data-ng-controller="MapsCtrl"  style="height: 100%"> <!--took out: ng-if="map.center !== undefined"-->
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='map.center'
                        zoom='map.zoom'
                        draggable='map.draggable'
                        dragging='map.dragging'
                        refresh='map.refresh'
                        options='map.options'
                        events='map.events'
                        pan='map.pan'>


        <ui-gmap-circle 
                        center='map.circle.center'
                        radius='map.circle.radius'
                        fill='map.circle.fill'
                        stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                        clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                        draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                        editable='map.circle.editable'
                        visible='map.circle.visible'
                        events='map.circle.events'>

        </ui-gmap-circle>


    </ui-gmap-google-map>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does `console.log($stateParams)` look like?

Comment: searchRadius.js:42 Object__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 2name: "__defineGetter__"__proto__: ()<function scope>__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 1name: "__lookupSetter__"__proto__: ()<function scope>constructor: Object()arguments: nullassign: assign()caller: nullcreate: create()defineProperties: defineProperties()defineProperty:

Comment: code seems to be fine. are you getting any errors? try removing `resolve` and run? and also `params` as it has no effect.

Comment: @Pradeepb No errors, just a blank screen (if you go to the link in my post) and when I alert the stringified 'center' object it shows both latitude and longitude are null. Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: I went through the link(sorry, you are right. there are no errors). May be I am missing small details then.